# How to add message box with 'OK' button?

Tags: android, messagebox

I want to display a message box with an OK button. I used the following code but it results in a compile error with argument:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dlgAlert.setMessage("This is an alert with no consequence");
dlgAlert.setTitle("App Title");
dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
dlgAlert.create().show();
```

How should I go about displaying a message box in Android?

Comment: Somehow your code worked as is for me. May be my sdk settings `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />` has something to do with it as to why I didn't get any compilation error which you are suggesting.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think there may be problem that you haven't added click listener for ok positive button.

```
dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //dismiss the dialog  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 35):

Since in your situation you only want to notify the user with a short and simple message, a `Toast` would make for a better user experience.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> **Update:** A [Snackbar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbar/) is recommended now instead of a Toast for Material Design apps.

If you have a more lengthy message that you want to give the reader time to read and understand, then you should use a `DialogFragment`. (The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) currently recommends wrapping your `AlertDialog` in a fragment rather than calling it directly.)

Make a class that extends `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("App Title");
        builder.setMessage("This is an alert with no consequence");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // You don't have to do anything here if you just 
                // want it dismissed when clicked
            }
        });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Then call it when you need it in your activity:

```
DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragmentTag");
```

#### See also

- [Android Alert Dialog with one, two, and three buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513919/android-alert-dialog-with-one-two-and-three-buttons)

[image]

Comment: Great idea about the Toast.  For me it required the import: [import android.widget.Toast;]

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager?

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy, There is a good chance that this code is out of date. Feel free to edit my answer or add a new one if you find an updated solution. (I'm working on Flutter now so I haven't been keeping up with what's happening in Android native.)

Answer (score 9):

The code compiles ok for me. May be you have forgotten to add the import:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

Anyway, you have a good tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog).

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case 0:
    {               
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("text here")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {                   
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
            {
                try
                {

                }//end try
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }//end catch
            }//end onClick()
        }).create();                
    }//end case
  }//end switch
    return null;
}//end onCreateDialog
```

Comment: this dialog won't show without a call to alertDialog.show();