# Return message if no checkbox is selected

Tags: java, android

How to implement more into this code so that it returns a message telling the user to 'select at least one checkbox' if he/ she does not select any?

```
public void verificaCheckBox() {

    Listcheck.clear();

    if (cbPapel.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbPapel.getText().toString());

    if (cbPlastico.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbPlastico.getText().toString());

    if (cbMetal.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbMetal.getText().toString());

    if (cbVidro.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbVidro.getText().toString());

    cbSelecionado = (Listcheck.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String verificaCheckBox(){

Listcheck.clear();

if (cbPapel.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbPapel.getText().toString());

if (cbPlastico.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbPlastico.getText().toString());

if (cbMetal.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbMetal.getText().toString());

if (cbVidro.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbVidro.getText().toString());


    cbSelecionado = (Listcheck.toString());

return Listcheck.isEmpty() ? "Message goes here" : "";

}
```

Then wherever calls it can check to see if the return is an empty string or the message.  If you just want to show the user a message you could do this:

```
public void verificaCheckBox(){

Listcheck.clear();

if (cbPapel.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbPapel.getText().toString());

if (cbPlastico.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbPlastico.getText().toString());

if (cbMetal.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbMetal.getText().toString());

if (cbVidro.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbVidro.getText().toString());


    cbSelecionado = (Listcheck.toString());

if(Listcheck.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Alert Dialog to accomplish that.
I believe that the following link gives more relevant details on how to do so:
[How to add message box with ok button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264694/how-to-add-message-box-with-ok-button)

To put it for you in simpler steps:

- Add an else-statement at the end of your code.
- Use the Alert Dialog to notify the user of the changes needed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understood your question, but if you want to send message to the user you can use a `Toast`

For example:

```
if (Listcheck.size() == 0)
   Toast.makeText(this, "select at least one checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```